# Internal Vulnerability scans - defining the applicability

Tags: pci-dss

If a service provider has a network with thin clients, and they use a citrix portal to access a PCI complaint service provider's cardholder data environment.

If the environment is very similar to tho this and if it is merchant, (with applicable SAQ C-VT), the scans will be not applicable anyway !!

what is the value in having an internal network vulnerability scan, if it is service provider?

is it possible to de-scope it, and make it not applicable ?

Comment: You really need to talk to your QSA to get a decision on that.